# Make Form2 label text value change by combobox and update exactly when combobox was updated

Tags: c#, forms, combobox, label

In `Form2`

- I set a public static string to `form2text`
- then I set label text value equal to `form2text`

In `Form1`

- under `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`: `Form2.form2text = comboBox1.Text;`

How do I get this label to update exactly when the combo box was changed, rather then having to click on label every time I want it to update?

I don't want to open `Form2` every time the combo box has been changed.

I want it update inside of `Form2`.

Comment: Instead of a public string, make a public METHOD on Form2 that receives the String and then sets both the backing variable and updates the corresponding label?

Comment: when you had originally said this i didn't completely understand but now i do... thanks man i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

after lots of testing I found certain variations simply would not work in the way I wanted (that being the second form closing and re-opening every time I changed a value). I originally used a string with a timer to update that string but as we both know that's extremely inefficient so here is the answer:

```
 Form2 f2 = new Form2(); // set the name for your second form
f2.label1.Text = Combobox.Text; // make Form2 equal what you want I used combobox
```

Make sure you set the **Modifiers** to **Public** in your **Properties** Section.

Comment: This still doesn't seem right.  If Form1 opens Form2, you simply need to move that Form2 reference from local to class level and get rid of the static.

Comment: it works perfectly and I'm not sure why it doesn't seem right to you? I tried what you said and got it to work but I found it could be way simpler with this code instead.